# Angular UI Bootstrap asynchronous typeahead: $viewValue undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up a second typeahead in my ngViews, and even though my code is nearly identical to the first, the first works perfectly, while the second passes 'undefined' to the callback.

Here's the markup for non-functional typeahead:

```
<div id="toNodePicker" ng-if="!toNode.NodeId">
    <label for="to-node-name">Pick a node:</label>
    <input id="to-node-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter node"
           typeahead-wait-ms=" 50"
           typeahead-min-length="3"
           ng-model="selectedToNode"
           typeahead="toResult.Name for toResult in nodeSearch($viewvalue)" />
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
.controller('edgeAddCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'graphService', 'resourceService',
function ($scope, $routeParams, graphService, resourceService) {
    var fromType = null;
    var toType = null;
    $scope.selectedToNode = undefined;
    $scope.toNode = {};
    $scope.fromNodeSel = undefined;
    $scope.fromNode = {};

    if ($routeParams.nodeId) {
        graphService.getNode($routeParams.nodeId)
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.fromNode = data.data;
            if ($scope.fromNode) {
                fromType = $scope.fromNode.NodeTypeId;
            }

            if ($scope.toNode) {
                toType = $scope.toNode.NodeTypeId;
            }

            graphService.getEdgeTypes(fromType, toType)
                .then(function (data) {
                    $scope.edgeTypes = data.data;
                    $scope.selectedEdgeType = {};
                });
        });
    }
    $scope.nodeSearch = function(s) {
        return graphService.getNodesForNewEdge(s, 'to', $scope.fromNode, $scope.toNode, $scope.selectedEdgeType.EdgeTypeId)
                .then(function(data) {
                    return data.data;
                });
        }

    $scope.edgeTypes = [];
}]);
```

The only differences left between the functional and the non-functional typeahead that I can spot are the variable names and the callback, yet *s* is consistently **undefined** every time I hit my breakpoint in *nodeSearch*.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe it should be viewValue instead of viewvalue. Notice the cap. 'V'

Comment: Why doesn't information like this show up in the console?  Is there a way to get bindings to log exceptions, such as using an undefined variable like this?